# Spring boot Eureka Server Client throws connection timeouts under docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, netflix-eureka, windows-server-2016

I have been using docker Desktop CE on Windows Server 2016 from last 1.5 years.
I am running Spring Boot Micro services inside docker.
From last couple of days, I am getting network connection timeout errors suddenly on this.

The only solution is to restart the Docker Desktop for the above issue.
I tried to update the docker desktop, but it says your windows version is not supported.

> Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise (15063+) or Windows 10 Home (19018+).

Windows Server 2016 is also upto date. So can anyone know, wether Docker Desktop CE is not supported now by Docker on Windows Server 2016?

Some Facts

- I am running Linux Containers
- I am using 7 micro services
- Docker Version:- **Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962**

Eureka Engine Logs:-

```
    2020-07-05T08:18:20.660+0530 INFO Located environment: name=DIGIFLUX-engine, profiles=[default], label=null, version=30c3e10fdb4aa5743e99aea1189b11518c3174e9, state=null
2020-07-05T08:18:46.799+0530 INFO Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-07-05T08:19:46.799+0530 INFO Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-07-05T08:20:12.935+0530 INFO Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://10.10.1.2:8888/. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-07-05T08:20:12.936+0530 WARN Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://10.10.1.2:8888/DIGIFLUX-engine/default": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2020-07-05T08:20:25.132+0530 INFO Fetching config from server at : http://10.10.1.2:8888/
2020-07-05T08:20:25.608+0530 INFO Located environment: name=DIGIFLUX-engine, profiles=[default], label=null, version=30c3e10fdb4aa5743e99aea1189b11518c3174e9, state=null
2020-07-05T08:20:46.799+0530 INFO Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-07-05T08:21:46.799+0530 INFO Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2020-07-05T08:22:46.800+0530 INFO Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Eureka Client Logs:-

```
2020-07-06T09:42:36.841+0530 WARN Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-07-06T09:42:36.842+0530 ERROR DiscoveryClient_digiflux-USER-SERVICE/6d14e1050c2d:digiflux-user-service:8763 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$7.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:152) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndUpdateDelta(DiscoveryClient.java:1085) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:967) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
2020-07-06T09:42:56.170+0530 ERROR Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://10.10.1.2:8761/eureka/}
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:529) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.sendHeartBeat(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:102) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1405) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 27 more
2020-07-06T09:42:56.172+0530 WARN Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-07-06T09:42:56.172+0530 ERROR DiscoveryClient_digiflux-USER-SERVICE/6d14e1050c2d:digiflux-user-service:8763 - was unable to send heartbeat!
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$3.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:92) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.sendHeartBeat(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:89) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.renew(DiscoveryClient.java:846) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$HeartbeatThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1405) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
2020-07-06T09:43:04.422+0530 INFO Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2020-07-06T09:43:11.849+0530 ERROR Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://10.10.1.2:8761/eureka/}
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.10.1.2:8761 timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getDelta(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:170) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$7.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:152) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$7.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:152) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$7.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:152) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$7.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:152) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getDelta(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:149) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndUpdateDelta(DiscoveryClient.java:1085) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:967) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446) [eureka-client-1.9.8.jar!/:1.9.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.10.1.2:8761 timed out
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar!/:4.5.6]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    ... 30 more
```

Eureka engine configuration

```
spring.application.name=digiflux-engine
server.port=8761

gateway.host=10.10.1.2


# eureka by default will register itself as a client. So, we need to set it to false.
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://${gateway.host}:8888

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, loggers, threaddump, heapdump, httptrace, refresh
spring.profiles.active=default


eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms=25000 #Recently added. Attempted to solve issue
```

Eureka Client Config

```
spring.application.name=digiflux-leave-service
server.port=8765

gateway.host=10.10.1.2
gateway.port=8080
## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://${gateway.host}:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, loggers, threaddump, heapdump, httptrace, refresh

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

## File Storage Properties
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=./uploads

eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${gateway.host}:8761/eureka/


#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
#spring.cloud.config.uri=http://${gateway.host}:8888
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health, info, metrics, loggers, threaddump, heapdump, httptrace, refresh
spring.profiles.active=${ACTIVE_PROFILE:dev}

## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

## File Storage Properties
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=./uploads

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://${gateway.host}:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${gateway.host}:8761/eureka/

http.read.timeout=5000
http.connection.timeout=5000
```

Comment: What looks like your eureka client configuration? How are you specifying the eureka server address?

Comment: Question Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using static IPS in configuration? Container and docker bridge IP will change when they restart. Try to connect using [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) and the container name.

Comment: Making a bridge network made an improvement. Thanks